# How do i uninstall mysql-5.1.73-linux-x86_64-glibc23.tar.gz without using the rpm command on linux?

Tags: mysql, linux

I want uninstall mysql on my server without using the rpm command or apk-get command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try as per below-

```
yum erase Mysql*
```

Comment: Thank you so much i got it right